# Import Error : DLL module could not found, while importing pandas

Tags: python, dllimport

I am working on Python 3.5 and I am importing Pandas, Numpy, scikit-learn and pickle libraries in pycharm IDE. I have installed all the libraries as well, via pycharm IDE's package installer. When i execute following commands it gives me no "Syntax" errors in IDE.

```
import pickle
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

When i Execute my code it gives me following error for specifically importing "pandas" library. -->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/InputFile.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\sneha\AppData\Local\Temp\InputFile.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Users\sneha\AppData\Local\Temp\InputFile.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Users\sneha\AppData\Local\Temp\InputFile.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\Users\sneha\AppData\Local\Temp\InputFile.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\sneha\AppData\Local\Temp\InputFile.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\sneha\AppData\Local\Temp\InputFile.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3978, in <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Users\sneha\AppData\Local\Temp\InputFile.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8891, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core import window as rwindow
  File "C:\Users\sneha\AppData\Local\Temp\InputFile.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window as _window
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have seached for this and tried different solutions, but could not solve this errors.

Tried Solutions :

- [The specified module could not be found. DLL load failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717513/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-dll-load-failed)
- [the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-dll-load-failed](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwpN6i3pvbAhUKQ48KHZ5dBW0QrAIIMSgCMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F41407079%2Fimport-error-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-when-usin&usg=AOvVaw0FwBZuey32OV0zPNlnvivl)
- [the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-dll-load-failed](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwpN6i3pvbAhUKQ48KHZ5dBW0QrAIIMigDMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F20201868%2Fimporterror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found&usg=AOvVaw3dHHYvcNxO9iBaGKY-rayc)

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling pandas by typing this in the **command-prompt**

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I installed pandas 0.23.0
If you are using pandas 0.23.0, uninstall it and re-install 0.22.0

It worked for my case